# How to Create Web sql database offline

Tags: sqlite, cordova

i am Creating a project in phonegap and i want to use sql database i already create my database in sql lite
i want to know how to convert sql lite to websql and is there any application to create web sql 
(How to use web sql and where it is located in phonegap or chrome )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@ravi,

Hey, PhoneGap is working on WebView and this is created on HTML5. You know html have not directly supported sqlite. So, In phonegap inbuilt function.

In Phonegap Create first time database on Application Directory and use always this database by the Syntex. For More info Please Read [this](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html).

You can Create a new Project and in index.html only Copy Pest this Syntex.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Contact Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for PhoneGap to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Populate the database 
    //
    function populateDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
    }

    // Query the database
    //
    function queryDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
    }

    // Query the success callback
    //
    function querySuccess(tx, results) {
        var len = results.rows.length;
        console.log("DEMO table: " + len + " rows found.");
        for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
            console.log("Row = " + i + " ID = " + results.rows.item(i).id + " Data =  " + results.rows.item(i).data);
        }
    }

    // Transaction error callback
    //
    function errorCB(err) {
        console.log("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
    }

    // Transaction success callback
    //
    function successCB() {
        var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
        db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
    }

    // PhoneGap is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
        db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <p>Database</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks MRT    i alreday read this  and  i know that  phonegap is working on websql ...  but  i want to create database offline    if you know php where phpmyadmin is a location where all database was stored  and we can easily maintane and use that database like phpmyadmin is their any facility in phonegap or html5  to check my current database

Comment: @ravi if, working then Enjoy PhoneGap ... Cheers..
and I Request if succes your work, then accept my answer too..

Comment: your code is working butmy question is related to application where i can create database

Comment: Read this blog
http://gauravstomar.blogspot.in/2011/08/prepopulate-sqlite-in-phonegap.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+GauravSTomarBootstrappingIntelligence+%28Gaurav+S+Tomar+:+Bootstrapping+Intelligence